# how to open/close nodes on double/single click in jsTree

Tags: jquery, jstree

how can I **open/close** nodes on double or single **click** of the **node name**? Like it works here [the first tree sample](http://luban.danse.us/jazzclub/javascripts/jquery/jsTree/reference/_examples/5_others.html) - but there is used jsTree 0.9.8

- Using [jsTree 1.0rc2](http://www.jstree.com/)

-

```
<html>
<head>
<title> dashboard</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jstreegrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

$(document).ready(function(){

var data = [{
       data: "basics",
       attr: {SOF: "<a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>"},  
        children: [
         {data: "login", attr: {run: "run"},
           children: [                   
           {data: "login", attr: {}}
          ]
         } ,
         {data: "Academic Year", attr: {run: "run"},
          children: [                   
           {data: "login", attr: {}},
           {data: "Academic Year",  attr: {filter: "mini", SOF: "<a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>"}}
          ]

         }
        ]
      }];
$("div#jstree").jstree({
plugins: ["themes","json_data","grid","dnd"],
json_data: {data: data},
grid: {
        columns: [
          {width: 220, header: "Group"},
                        {cellClass: "col2", value: "run", width: 40, header: "run"},
                        {cellClass: "col3", value: "filter", width: 40, header: "filter"},
                        {cellClass: "col4", value: "SOF", width: 450, header: "SOF"}
                ]
            },
dnd: {
drop_finish : function () {
},
drag_finish : function () {
},
drag_check : function (data) {
return {
after : true,
before : true,
inside : true
};
}
}
});
});
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="jstree"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you want to toggle? visibility? some other style?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is to enable the types and ui plugins and define a select_node event handler on the default type like so:

```
   $(element)
        .jstree({ 
            "types" : { 
                "types" : { 
                    "default" : { 
                        "select_node" : function(e) {
                                            this.toggle_node(e);
                                            return false;
                                        } 

                    }
                } 
             },
             "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data","types", "ui" ] });
```

Comment: could you tell me where exactly in my code I need to insert your code?

Comment: Put the "types" block right before "plugins". Don't forget the comma! DOn't forget to add "ui" and "types" inside the "plugins" list.

Comment: If you are new to jsTree and looking for basic examples, check out my blog post http://tkgospodinov.com/jstree-part-1-introduction/. Hope that helps.

Comment: works nicely.... but the height of the selected/clicked row gets bigger so it whole tree is like moving. any idea how to prevent that? Or shall I create new question?

Comment: @TG: yes I am very new :-). Would you know how to fix this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891255/a-href-in-jstreegrid ps thank you for the link

Comment: is this solution outdated? seems not to work with jstree 3.1.1

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the correct answer from TK...

This solution will break the navigation when you click on tree items with href attribute (set by JSON, XML data or directly in HTML).

To solve this problem, in the leaf configured "types" (where anchors must trigger navigation) set this handler:

```
"select_node": function (e) {
   document.location = e.children("a").attr("href");
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont you have to add the `clickable: [...]` option when creating your tree?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#domainvariants').jstree({
    plugins : ["themes","html_data","ui","crrm"]
}).bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
    return data.instance.toggle_node(data.node);
});
```

Comment: This code gives me the following error when clicking an item: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toggle_node' of undefined"

Comment: I have version "jsTree 2.0.0-alpha"