# jsTree TYPE plugin events are ignored

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am unable to get the jsTree "Types" plugin to work in any capacity at all, and there are no errors firing anywhere that I can detect.

1.) I referred to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891697/how-to-open-close-nodes-on-double-single-click-in-jstree) to have the node open/close with a mouseclick, but the function does not ever get executed.

2.) For the "Types" plugin the [jsTree Plugin Documentation](http://www.jstree.com/plugins) says this:

> To set a node's type you can use set_type or *supply a type property*
>   with the node's data.

I suspect it's a setup problem because neither of the "Types" settings are working, yet the "contextmenu" plugin does work, so it appears all the scripts are in place and I'm doing something wrong for "Types"

Has anyone else encountered this, or does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div id="jstree"></div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#jstree').jstree({
            "types" : {
                "types" : {
                    "series_type" : {
                        "icon" : {
                            "image" : "images/seriesnode.png"
                        }
                    },
                    "default" : {
                        "select_node" : function(e) {
                            console.info(e);
                            this.toggle_node(e);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "plugins" : [ "types", "ui" , "contextmenu" ],
            "contextmenu": { "items": {} },
            "core" : {
                'data' : {
                    'url' : 'series_tree_data.php'
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**JSON data returned from AJAX call:**

```
[
    {   "id":"series_123120",
        "parent":"#",
        "text":"1945 - The Year That Changed The World",
        "type":"series_type",
        "state":{"opened":true}
    },
    {   "id":"title_2003150",
        "parent":"series_123120",
        "text":"Beginning of the End",
    },
    {   "id":"segment_3006200",
        "parent":"title_2003150",
        "text":"Full Program",
    },
    {   "id":"file_552973",
        "parent":"segment_3006200",
        "text":"1945_part_1.flv",
        "icon":false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in the documentation at [http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.defaults.types](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=%24.jstree.defaults.type) , theres no mention of "select_node", so it would seem that portion should not work at all.  I'd check to see if you have the latest library.

Comment: Looks like that's it....not often a new version of something has less in it....but at least I can stop scratching my head

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble with the types, this worked for me:

```
$('#jstree').jstree({
                "types":{
                   "key" : {
                       "icon": "Content/Images/skey.png"
                    },
                   "value": {
                       "icon": "Content/Images/sValue.png"
                   }
                },
```

you might also want to play around with adding a_attr: "rel": "series_type" to your data.

good luck

Comment: Thanks @amda ... I think the confusion lies in most googling returns results for an older (and quite widespread) version with a number of those features no longer included in the latest (which I downloaded).  The "Type" functions don't seem to be supported anymore (or at least yet), nor does Themeroller.  It was actually the "select_node" : function(e) {} that I was trying to implement, but could not get that to fire to save my soul, lol.

Comment: @GDP - Yes i am having similar issues. The type is supported in new version, but the theme is not. Did you get it to work?

Comment: @amda...I wound up binding an event to the click processing I wanted...it seems that the Types has enormous potential that's going unutilized...sigh